# Testing React Native via iPhone IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, reactjs, react-native

This may be a bit of a silly question but i haven't found a solid answer.
I have created a React Native app which includes making http requests to an external server (https://example.com).

When i plug my iPhone in, connect to wifi and deploy to device it works great. (All certificate signing etc is fine).

Should this app still work on my phone once I have disconnected it from my macbook and/or disconnected it from the same wifi.

It worked initially but then eventually kept crashing on load.

As soon as i plugged it back in and tested it works. Is there a way to keep this app on my device permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't work. While you're testing it, the application on your phone is loading your React Native JS code bundle from a server running on your computer, normally on `http://localhost:8081`.

Once the phone loses access to that server, the app on the phone will lose access to that JS bundle and it will crash.

You have to install the app on your phone by creating an IPA (which requires an Apple Developer account), so that the app can be used anytime.

Comment: Thanks. I've followed instructions to upload the app archive to itunes connect and deploy via testflight.

Comment: You could also look into an Ad Hoc Distribution